# What pattern should I use for refactoring my relational SQL database to a key-value store?

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring, relational-database, key-value, horizontal-scaling

I'm looking at migrating my web-application from an SQL database to a key-value store, so I can scale my app horizontally.

I'm planning out how to migrate my schema - and I'm sure there must be a pattern for doing this.

I'll give a Mickey Mouse logical example to show my thinking. Here is a simple library system in a relational database with `Book`s, `Person`s and `BorrowEvent`s. You can join from the `Book`s to the `Person`s using the `BorrowEvent` to see who has borrowed which `Book`.

```
Book
 - BookID
 - BookTitle

Person
 - PersonID
 - PersonName

BorrowEvent
 - BorrowEventID
 - BookID
 - PersonID
```

Now let's try the following refactor:

```
[Key][Value]
 - ID/BookName
 - ID/PersonName
 - ID/[String]"BorrowEvent-"+[ID of BookName]+"-"+[ID of PersonName]
```

This works by querying on the BorrowEvent, splitting the String of the value using a regex to get the IDs.

Now this has several limitations. If I want to have add an `Author` to my `Book`, I've got to add an additional hop to retrieve my book information. Same goes if I want the `Person` to have a first and last name.

I imagine there must be a *pattern* for this transformation from relational to key-value store. (Or multiple patterns). I just don't know what the name is.

My question is: **What pattern should I use for refactoring my relational SQL database to a key-value store?**

**Assumptions**:

- Assume this is a logical refactor, not a physical refactor.

Comment: This seems close: https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/

Comment: Relational databases can generally handle n-ary relations; a decomposition into binary relations can imply integrity and/or performance penalties as you reinvent relational DBMS features in your own code.  I'm reminded of Einstein's quote to "make things as simple as possible but no simpler".

Comment: Or the quote: "For every complex problem there is an answer that is clear, simple, and wrong."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post lists](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) a number of techniques, including:

1. Dimensionality Reduction
2. Index Table
3. Composite Key Index
4. Aggregation with Composite Keys
5. Inverted Search - Direct Aggregation
6. Tree Aggregation
7. Adjacency Lists
8. Materialised Paths
9. Nested Sets
10. Nested Documents Flattening

    i. Numbered Field Names

    ii. Proximity Queries
11. Batch Graph Processing